Open a modal inside an element in an {#each ... } loop
Problem: Every time I open the modal in one of the child components in the loop it always opens the modal in the last element of the loop. I cannot make it open the modal of the other child elements even though I try to trigger their modal.
My code looks like this:
Parent component (+page.svelte):
<script lang="ts">
    import type { PageData } from './$types';
    import { Heading } from 'flowbite-svelte';
    import Card from './Card.svelte';

    export let data: PageData;
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>Content</title>
    <meta name="overview" content="Overview of contents" />
</svelte:head>

<Heading tag="h3" class="mb-12">Your content</Heading>

<div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-8 2xl:grid-cols-4 3xl:grid-cols-5">
    {#each data.contents as content}
        <Card {content} />
    {/each}
</div>

Child component (Card.svelte):
<script lang="ts">
    import type { ContentListDTO } from '@content-service/content_dto';
    import { formatRelative } from 'date-fns';
    import {
        Card,
        Dropdown,
        DropdownItem,
        GradientButton,
        Input,
        Label,
        Modal
    } from 'flowbite-svelte';
    import {
        ArrowRightOutline,
        DotsVerticalOutline,
        FileInvoiceOutline
    } from 'flowbite-svelte-icons';

    export let content: ContentListDTO;

    let openRenameModal = false;

    function capitalizeFirstLetter(value: string) {
        return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
    }

    const createdAt = capitalizeFirstLetter(formatRelative(new Date(content.createdAt), new Date()));
</script>

<Card class="relative">
    <div class="img-bg bg-gray-200 rounded-t-lg">
        <FileInvoiceOutline
            strokeWidth="1"
            class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 text-white w-16 h-16"
        />
    </div>

    <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
        {content.title}
    </h5>
    <p class="mb-8 font-extralight text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 leading-tight">
        Created: {createdAt}
    </p>

    <div>
        <GradientButton pill color="blue" class="w-fit">
            Edit <ArrowRightOutline class="w-6 h-6 ms-2 text-white" />
        </GradientButton>

        <DotsVerticalOutline
            class="dots-menu float-right mt-2 -mr-3 w-8 h-8 dark:text-white cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-200 rounded"
        />
        <Dropdown triggeredBy=".dots-menu">
            <DropdownItem on:click={() => (openRenameModal = true)}
                ><span class="font-light">Rename</span></DropdownItem
            >
            <DropdownItem><span class="text-red-600 font-light">Delete</span></DropdownItem>
        </Dropdown>
    </div>
</Card>

<Modal size="xs" bind:open={openRenameModal} autoclose outsideclose>
    <form class="flex flex-col space-y-6" action="#">
        <h3 class="mb-4 text-xl font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Rename content</h3>
        <Label class="space-y-2">
            <span>Current content title</span>
            <Input
                type="text"
                name="currentTitle"
                disabled
                readonly
                class="focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500"
                value={content.title}
            />
        </Label>
        <Label class="space-y-2">
            <span>New content title</span>
            <Input type="text" name="title" required class="focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-blue-500" />
        </Label>
        <GradientButton type="submit" color="blue" class="w-full1">Rename content</GradientButton>
    </form>
</Modal>

So far, I've tried to move the modal to the parent component without any success as well as trying various bind directives.

It looks like Svelte is having difficulty tracking which instance of Card you are interacting with. Try adding a unique key to each element of your each loop, something like {#each data.contents as content (content.id)}. You can replace content.id with any unique identifier, event strings, so content.name could be another choice for example.

Thanks for the suggestion. The content model does have a unique id and I tried adding it as a unique key to the element. Unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue..

Sorry, I am not familiar with flowbite components at all. Are you sure you should have multiple instances of Modal like this? Perhaps you could hoist up a single instance of Modal into the page, and pass it the correct event reference through an event or a callback?

Sorry meant the correct content reference, not event!

No problem, I'm also new to both Svelte and Flowbite. I've also tried to take the modal out in the parent component and then trigger and populate it with a single selected content instance there. However, I don't think it's the modal instance but instead the triggering that fails, because it seems like it's only the last element in the loop that gets triggered even though I select the other elements. Thank you so far for looking into this :)

Added what I think is a minimal reproduction, except it seems to work just fine as is? https://svelte.dev/repl/f540879ff7d54f22981f7585272d6822?version=4.2.17 (obviously lacks styling, but the modals still work as intended)

Thank you so much for your help. Your code example helped me figure out where the problem was. It turned out that all dropdown elements from each card got triggered when I clicked a single card, but I couldn't see it since they we're all right on top of each other. Since the dropdown from last card was rendered lastly, it got on top of all the other dropdowns.. that way, it was always last modal that was triggered when I clicked it. To fix it, I changed triggeredBy in Dropdown element to a unique DOM id for each card dropdown element.

Maybe this is more of a workaround than a solution but try wrapping your modal inside an IF block like so:
{#if openRenameModal}
<Modal size="xs" bind:open={openRenameModal} autoclose outsideclose>
 
</Modal>
{/if}

This should make sure that only the modal of the specific element that sets the openRenameModal variable to true exists. It would help more to debug if you provide a minimal reproducer.

Interesting solution.. I tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work. I don't think it's the modal instance but instead the triggering that fails, because it seems like it's only the last element in the loop that gets triggered even though I select the other elements. Thank you so far for looking into this :)
